# Install pysqlite in virtualenv with python3 support

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I've created virtualenv with:

```
mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 django
```

After, I tried install pysqlite:

```
pip install pysqlite
```

But I got:

```
Downloading/unpacking pysqlite
  Downloading pysqlite-2.6.3.tar.gz (76kB): 76kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/sigo/.virtualenvs/django/build/pysqlite/setup.py) egg_info for package pysqlite
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/home/sigo/.virtualenvs/django/build/pysqlite/setup.py", line 85
        print "Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'."
                                                                           ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/home/sigo/.virtualenvs/django/build/pysqlite/setup.py", line 85

    print "Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'."

                                                                       ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems that pip try use python2. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Check that you have pip for python 3. This will be named something like `pip-3.2`.

Comment: Using pip3 and pip3.4 causes the same error.

Comment: A quick look seems to suggest you need to install `pysqlite3`

Comment: That syntax error about the print statement reveals pysqlite is written in Python2, not Python3. sadlly, seems like the @ghaering answer is right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no public version of pysqlite for Python 3.x. For Python 3.x, the sqlite3 module in the standard library is the most up-to date version of pysqlite there is.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to get FTS3/4 support for sqlite3 then? I was hoping to get it by installing a pysqlite with pip.

Comment: If Python loads a SQLite shared library with FTS3/FTS4 support, then you're fine. The Python sqlite3 module or pysqlite do not need to be recompiled.

Comment: If you download the latest sqlite-autoconf-* file and install it with

./configure --prefix=/opt/sqlite3
make -j4 install

then it is by default built with the fts3 and rtree extensions. You can then

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/sqlite3/lib

and subsequently started Python processes will pick up the just installed sqlite3 library. On Mac, it's DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm following [this](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-the-sqlite-json1-and-fts5-extensions-with-python/)
 procedure to include the JSON1 extension for SQLite.

When running the

```
python setup.py install
```

command for `pysqlite` within a virtual environment (`miniconda`) I receive the following output:

> pysqlite is not supported on Python 3. When using Python 3, use the
>   sqlite3 module from the standard library.

Setting

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/bin/jqlite/lib
```

doesn't change this.

Comment: My fault. I got confused here. Pysqlite is not needed as I understand and by setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH within the virtual environment it should be possible to use the JSON1 extension of the sqlite3 module. I will check and provide information on that soon.