# Python3 won't recognize sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

I have python3 installed on linux. In the python interpreter, I tried

```
import sqlite3
```

and got

```
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

so i installed sqlite with

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite-dev
```

and then recompiled python according to the instructions in the README file:

```
cd ~/Python-3.4.2;
./configure;
make;
make test;
```

and during test there was an error saying

```
[ 97/389] test_sqlite
test_sqlite skipped -- No module named '_sqlite3'
```

and then when I finished the install and tried to run the same python code, I still got the same ImportError. What am I doing wrong?

---EDIT---

I tried

```
pip install pysqlite
```

and got this error, which seems to be an issue between Python2.7 and Python3.4:

```
Downloading/unpacking pysqlite
  Downloading pysqlite-2.6.3.tar.gz (76kB): 76kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_plat/pysqlite/setup.py) egg_info for package pysqlite
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_plat/pysqlite/setup.py", line 85
        print "Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'."
                                                                           ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_plat/pysqlite/setup.py", line 85

    print "Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'."

                                                                       ^

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_plat/pysqlite
Storing debug log for failure in /home/plat/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: The package you are trying to install is not compatible with Python 3.

Comment: The issue is that your Python was built *without* sqlite support; where the `sqlite` development headers installed when you compiled it?

Comment: This might be a dupe of [How to install pysqlite for python3.4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26438307) but that post wasn't answered.

Comment: I ran into the same problem.  My fix was to 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev' and not 'libsqlite3-dev'.  I assume libsqlite-dev is for python 2 and not python 3.  After that the make test passed.

Answer (score -2):

After install libsqlite-dev you should install pysqlite

```
pip install pysqlite
```

Comment: I tried this, and posted the error message in the original question.