# No module named '_sqlite3' error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-1.7

Python 2.6 and Django 1.6 was installed on the server (Suse).
I installed Python 3.4 and Django 1.7.

I can run

> django-admin.py startproject hi

Once I run any command related to manage.py like

> python manage.py syncdb

I will get this error

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as Database
ImportError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 35, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 40, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 297, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 166, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 242, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 108, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named '_sqlite3'
```

according to [Install pysqlite in virtualenv with python3 support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181197/install-pysqlite-in-virtualenv-with-python3-support)
There is no public version of pysqlite for Python 3.x.

Also, I installed sqlite-autoconf-3080704. and still I get the same error message.

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have only a minimum installation of Python 3. If you're using Debian or a Debian-based system like Ubuntu, you can do `apt-get install python3` to install the full version.