# Python sqlite3 not using index with LIKE

Tags: python, indexing, sqlite

I have a table with a single column, which I query in two ways:

- `SELECT * FROM sequences WHERE seqs="blablabla"`
- `SELECT * FROM sequences WHERE seqs LIKE "blablabla%"`

For these queries to use an index I seem to need two indices (one for each query type), as such:

- `CREATE INDEX test_nocol ON sequences(seqs)` for the first query.
- `CREATE INDEX seqs_index ON sequences(seqs COLLATE NOCASE)` for the second query.

That's all nice, but then I add python3's sqlite3 module, and start querying there instead, which works with raw strings, but when I use parameter bindings the `COLLATE` index is suddenly no longer used:

```
>>> sql = 'explain query plan\n select seqs from sequences where seqs="blabla"'
>>> c3.execute(sql).fetchall()
[(0, 0, 0, 'SEARCH TABLE sequences USING COVERING INDEX test_nocol (seqs=?)')]
>>> sql = 'explain query plan\n select seqs from sequences where seqs=?'
>>> c3.execute(sql, ('hahahah',)).fetchall()
[(0, 0, 0, 'SEARCH TABLE sequences USING COVERING INDEX test_nocol (seqs=?)')]
>>> sql = 'explain query plan\n select seqs from sequences where seqs like "hahahah%"'
>>> c3.execute(sql).fetchall()
[(0, 0, 0, 'SEARCH TABLE sequences USING COVERING INDEX seqs_index (seqs>? AND seqs<?)')]
>>> sql = 'explain query plan\n select seqs from sequences where seqs like ?'
>>> c3.execute(sql, ('hahahah',)).fetchall()
[(0, 0, 0, 'SCAN TABLE sequences')]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Since this is a serialization backend and not a webapp DB, I guess the threat when using raw strings is less severe, but I'd much rather use the proper SQL formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#like_opt) says:

> If the right-hand side is a [parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) that is bound to a string, then this optimization is only attempted if the [prepared statement](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) containing the expression was compiled with [sqlite3_prepare_v2()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) or [sqlite3_prepare16_v2()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html). The LIKE optimization is not attempted if the right-hand side is a [parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) and the statement was prepared using [sqlite3_prepare()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) or [sqlite3_prepare16()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html).

Old versions of the pysqlite module use `sqlite3_prepare()`.

Comment: Thanks, using pysqlite from PyPI instead of the python std library sqlite3 (v.2.6.0) module fixes this. Unfortunately I'm on python3 and the pysqlite package is not available (yet). http://stackoverflow.com/a/23414147/1271862