# Pysqlite2 error while starting django project

Tags: python, django

Im trying to start a django project from scratch but i have an error that says **"ImportError: No Module Named 'pysqlite2'"**

I'm using Python 3.6.0. I will write steps which im following

---

```
Creating project 

> django-admin startproject testproject

Trying to start an app

> python manage.py startapp demo

Immediately after enters that command, it returns me a long text which includes error's path etc.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 34, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 36, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/home/berkin/pythonenv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 39, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): %s" % exc)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that order): No module named '_sqlite3'
```

What i tried?
- I installed sqlite3-dev with using sudo apt get ...
- I tried to install pip install pysqlite2
- I tried to alter source.py which is inside the virtual env folder but it wasnt worked.

But i figured out that when im not using virtual env, i mean without entering source /bin/activate, "python manage.py startapp demo" command has worked. When i activate env, it returns an error which i mentioned above.

Comment: what is the output of  `pip freeze | grep pysql` when you run this command in your activated virtualenv?

Comment: @matyas it returns nothing :(

Comment: and only `pip freeze` ?

Comment: appdirs==1.4.2
Django==1.10.6
olefile==0.44
packaging==16.8
Pillow==4.0.0
psycopg2==2.7
pyparsing==2.1.10
six==1.10.0

Answer (score 0):

according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23414147/2174832

> There is no public version of pysqlite for Python 3.x. For Python 3.x,
>   the sqlite3 module in the standard library is the most up-to date
>   version of pysqlite there is.

run the command `pip install sqlite3` within your activated virtualenv and use this module instead of pysqlite2. To activate your virtualenv go to `/folderofvirtualenv/bin` 
and run the command `source activate`

Comment: Collecting pysqlite2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pysqlite2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pysqlite2

Comment: which version of python (2 or 3) did you use to create your virtualenv?

Comment: ok the problem occurs because of the combination of pysqlite2 and python3 I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but i guess i need to configure my python am i right? What should i do now? I cant start an app with these circumstance

Comment: you need to set up sqlite3 as your django database backend in your settings.py file: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/ After that run `python manage.py syncdb` and you should be able to use your models in your code

Comment: and make sure to run `pip install sqlite3`before you change your database configuration in your settings.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137300/discussion-between-berkin-and-matyas).